# concatenating a comma character to a string

Tags: php

I'm using php to generate an href that should call on a javascript function
here's what I had attempted so far:

```
echo "<td><a href=". "#" . " onclick=" . "edit_pub(" . $row["Publication_no"] . "," . $row["Title"] . ")" . ">edit</a></td>";
```

which I had expected to generate:

```
<td><a href="#" onclick=edit_pub(parm1,parm2)>edit</a></td>
```

when I click the href I get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: asd is not defined

where asd is the second param

I've tried echoing 2 strings with a comma in between:

```
$title = $row["Title"] . ' , ' . "test";
echo $title;
```

That only prints the first variable.
How can I print something like:

```
param1,param2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, `asd` is a string, so the resulting output looks like:

```
...edit_pub(xxx, asd)...
```

You can see that `asd` is not quoted on the client.  If you're echoing out strings, you need to make sure you remember to requote them for JavaScript:

```
echo "<td><a href=". "#" . " onclick=" . "edit_pub('" . $row["Publication_no"] . "','" . $row["Title"] . "')" . ">edit</a></td>";
```